# Is HTTP pipelining supported in iOS?

Tags: ios, http, pipelining

I'm wondering whether [HTTP pipelining](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_pipelining) is supported in iOS or if I have to create the [body](https://developers.google.com/prediction/docs/reference/v1.5/batch#example) of the `multipart/mixed` request myself.

Comment: Did you solve this issue/

Answer (score 0):

Yes HTTP pipelining is supported in ios 5, have not really tried using it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

If you make request you should specify httpShouldUsePipelining.

```swift
var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "SOME_URL")!)

request.httpShouldUsePipelining = true
```

Comment: Can you please provide me example if possible?

Answer (score 0):

Sort of. iOS supports HTTP pipelining for a limited set of request methods. Per https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsmutableurlrequest/1412705-httpshouldusepipelining :

> Setting this property to true value does not guarantee HTTP pipelining behavior. This may have no effect if an HTTP proxy is configured, or if the HTTP request uses an unsafe request method—for example, POST requests will not pipeline.